# Laravel select() don't work with params when they have spaces

Tags: php, laravel, select

I have simple part of code:

```
$r=Input::get('r');
$sql='SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name`=?';
$dis=\DB::connection('old-dis')->select($sql, [$r]);
```

When $r don't has spaces, everything works corretly. But when $r is for simple `teddy bear` Laravel show me error and doesn't add `' '` to my text. I find next solution:

```
if(strpos($r,' ')) $r="'$r'";
```

Anyone has better way  to fix it?

Comment: `$r=Input::get("'r'");` check now

Comment: why are you even using raw queries in laravel?

Comment: @Abdulla - it's not working with Request::get() :<

Comment: @Luceos - I'm in work and I have indication to use raw SQL. Later we will rewrite all to models, but at this moment we using pure SQL. It's not my idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I used `DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work better.

```
$r=Input::get("r");

$results = DB::connection('old-dis')
->select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = :variable"), [
    "variable"=>$r,
]);

dd($results);
```

Comment: What is with validation? I think when I do query in DB::raw() someone can do SQL attack. I think correctly?

Comment: Sure there's always a posibility of sql attacks, but when you bind the variable with pdo/mysqli, they cant just replace the variable with new sql. So thats some security atleast, but as Luceos wrote in your comment section its more consistant and better to use models instead of using raw queries.

Comment: Thanks @oBo - I'm using SQL queries because I must do it. Later we will rewrite it, but now we using SQL queries, not models :/

Comment: You should validate the $_GET['r'] value before in insert it into the db. (example validate it to be only digits or whatever)